# Write 'ß' (Eszett) German letter on English Windows 10 PRO with Spanish Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

*If is it off-topic, please tell me, the site.*

I have a Laptop with Spanish Keyboard.

[image]

My Language Settings on my `Windows 10 PRO` is English :

[image]

And I was checking with Character Map:

[image]

I was testing with:
http://www.vienayyo.com/como-escribir-la-s-con-el-teclado-espanol/

```
1. AltGr + s 
2. ALT + 0223
3. ALT + 225
4. CTRL + ALT + s
5. Fn + ALT + 225
6. ALT + b
```

and with
https://www.aprendealeman.com/blog/como-escribir-con-el-teclado-espanol/

I was testing in alternative Booted OS (CentOS 8).

**In CentOS 8 -> Sublime Text (<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>), y en LibreOffice (<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>), Works!**

But, Unfortunately on my Windows 10 Pro, I can't get the 'ß' (Eszett) German Letter with Specific Keys Combination.

Is there alternative to (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + `0223`) Combination, without <kbd>Alt</kbd>
Some clue?

I was testing with  <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `(Letter)` <kbd>O</kbd>.

The circumflex `^` character; in Windows with Spanish Keyboard is obtained with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>  or with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: In wordpad or MS Word, type 00df then press ALT + X. Does it show the correct character?

Comment: Alt/Gr s works on a UK English keyboard [ISO] set to United States English International, but not in standard UK English. As you also have an ISO keyboard, you may generally do better with UK or International English as default rather than US, which is ANSI-based by default.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks, I was testing but does not works.